# Spring sets @PostMapping fields from GET url query?

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc

My setup is as follows:
I have a form and a table on the same page: `localhost:8080/persons?firstname=frank`

This shows all persons with firstname accordingly.
From the same page, it is possible to submit a form for creating new persons:

```
<form action="/persons" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/>
    <input type="text" name="firstname"/>
    <input type="text" name="lastname"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Create"/>
</form>
```

Problem: when I actually `POST` the form content to the `Spring` `@Controller`, the following content gets send:

URL: `/persons?firstname=frank`

Request Body: `_method=post&firstname=&lastname=doe`

Spring then magically merges GET-query params and POST form params into one DTO, and results in a `PersonDto` that has both firstname + lastname set

```
@PostMapping("/persons")
public void addPerson(PersonDto p) {
    //p.firstname => Frank, p.lastname = Doe
}

PersonDto {
    public String firstname, lastname, age;
}
```

Somehow `Spring` derives the request body values *also* from the get-query url parameters. Why??

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, just like you can map the request body to an Object, you can also do it with query parameters.

The reason might be the following:

> In Spring MVC, "request parameters" map to query parameters, form
> data, and parts in multipart requests. This is because the Servlet API
> combines query parameters and form data into a single map called
> "parameters", and that includes automatic parsing of the request body.

Reference documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html

Since the parameters are merged into a single map, you can get all of them in a single Object.

Comment: Okay, this is probably the cause. But can I work around it somehow? Eg disable the parsing of get-query params for a specific method?

Comment: Not really sure if this helps, but have you tried explicitly using `@RequestBody` annotation as in: `@RequestBody PersonDto p`?